# How can I export field level history for a field with tracking enabled?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, force.com

I want to export a history of changes to a single field on the Account object and have field level tracking enabled on the field.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll first have to turn on history tracking for the field by following the [instructions given here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=tracking_field_history_for_standard_objects.htm&language=en_US).

Once you've turned on history tracking for that field, any changes to that field will be recorded on the AccountHistory object.  You can view them in the History related list on Account, make a report on Account History where the Field Name equals that field, or download them from the AccountHistory object via the API.